# Parse text inbetween tabs

Tags: c#, excel, parsing

I have to copy and paste excel into a form and extract each value and since it's separated by tabs I'm doing something like:

```
var lines = PasteText.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (var currLine in lines.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)))
{
     var items = currLine.Split(new string[] { "\t", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Take(15).ToArray();
}
```

But a problem arises if there's a tab inside one of the column fields.

How could I go about solving this?

Comment: Well if there is a tab inside a column then a tab could not be the true delimiter in the first place, where does currLine come from?

Comment: If there's a tab in a column field it means there are two consecutive empty fields. You shouldn't use `RemoveEmptyEntries` but `None`. Otherwise you might get a different field-length in every line.

Comment: @AlexK. updated the code, if I can't use a tab as a delimiter how could I go about parsing excel?

Comment: @TimSchmelter say there it's some text like "text <tab> moretext"

Comment: @JoeViscardi: then you should complain at the guy who said that tab is the delimiter, obviously it is not. If it really is, then the csv is broken and can't be read. You (or who is responsible) should try to fix the root, so where it is generated.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is there and true delimiter if you're copying from an excel file then?

Comment: @JoeViscardi: i don't understand this question.

Comment: If your app is interacting with excel by clipboard-copying data then yes, it may lose information about delimiters when you read that back as tab is the default and does not consider in-cell tabs.  Office interop will let you read ranges directly by row/column index which is what you should probably be doing.

Comment: sorry @TimSchmelter had a typo, I meant is there any* true delimiter if it's being copied from an excel file